# Method in export is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I'm running into an issue where I am trying to call a function from a file where it is also being exported. How do I call this function? It's important that I am able to call this function from this file as well as export it for other uses. Thanks a ton for help on this!

I have added the relevant code below:

```
module.exports.handleCreatedTs = function(criteria, newSearch){  
    ...Lots of Calculations happen here...
}

module.exports.handleDateAndTermsDueDate = function(criteria, newSearch, isTermsDueDate){
var tempSearchObj = {};
handleCreatedTs(criteria, tempSearchObj); //This is where the exception is thrown

if(isTermsDueDate){
    newSearch.termsDueDate = tempSearchObj;
}
else{
    newSearch.date = tempSearchObj;
}
}

module.exports.handleInvoiceSupplierName = function(criteria, newSearch){
    if(criteria.operator != "equals"){
        return; //Not going to handle this
    }

    newSearch.supplierOrg.push({text: criteria.value, value: criteria.value});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a variable in your code `handleCreatedTs()`. You have an anonymous function assigned to, `module.exports.handleCreatedTs()`.

You *could* call it with `module.exports.handleCreatedTs()`, but it's probably cleaner define the named function first and add it to `module.exports` if you plan on calling it from within the module.

```
function handleCreatedTs(criteria, newSearch){  
   // ...Lots of Calculations happen here...
}

// you can call handleCreatedTs()

// export the function:
module.exports.handleCreatedTs = handleCreatedTs
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!